# JIRA webhook port workaround?

Tags: jenkins, jira

I've been tasked with implementing continuous integration for our staging server. I'm using Jenkins and JIRA, and would like to use the Jira Trigger Plugin to allow for creation of Jira issues on Build and triggers based on Jira status.

Following the plugin instructions [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jira-trigger-plugin), I need to create a webhook in JIRA, however, Cloud Jira has a known issue with webhooks:

> If you are using webhooks in JIRA Cloud, there is a known issue that restricts the port numbers that can be specified in the webhook URL. If you do not follow the guidelines below, then the webhook will not trigger.
>   If you are using HTTP and specify a port number in the webhook URL, the port number must be 80. Note, if you do not specify a port number, the webhook will still work.

I'm running Jenkins on port 8081 as 8080 and 80 are in use and not available to change. The webhook url is http://my.domain:8081/jira-trigger-webhook-receiver so Jira immediately refuses the URL as it's not on port 80. Not specifying the port, as suggested in the Jira documentation does not work.

So, is there a workaround for this so that I can get the webhook set up and be able to use this plugin?

Comment: If your Jenkins server is behind a firewall that you control, you could write a simple port forward that takes traffic from the JIRA Cloud IP(s) on port 80 and forwards that traffic to the Jenkins server on port 8081

Comment: Might want to vote on this feature: [JENKINS-33990](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33990)

Answer (score 0):

You can use nginx as a proxy server behind webhook service. Ensure the webhook url is using port 80.